# Redirect to 'www' before ssl requirement

Tags: php, redirect, ssl

**Problem**

I currently have the problem where https://domain.com does not redirect to https://www.domain.com and shows an untrusted ssl certificate.

This is Related to which is a ruby-on-rails solution
[redirect to 'www' before force_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506954/redirect-to-www-before-force-ssl)

**Question**

Is there a way to redirect to the www domain before the SSL requirement kicks in?

I am using PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect https to non-www and http to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725357/redirect-https-to-non-www-and-http-to-www)

Comment: @Bruno Looked at many cases but none defines the answer given by deceze

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I could more or less copy/paste the answer I gave to the other question to answer yours. (More or less the same as what deceze said indeed; the only thing he doesn't say is that you could achieve what you want by having a cert valid for both.) There are a number of questions about this around. Here is another one on SF: http://serverfault.com/a/360985/47187

Comment: thank you for have posted this question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

HTTPS is HTTP over TLS/SSL (see [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818)), which first establishes the SSL/TLS connection before any HTTP traffic is sent. Any redirection (via `mod_rewrite`, custom PHP code or other) will always apply after the SSL/TLS connection is established.

Not doing so would actually be a security issue, since an attacker could rewrite and redirect the client before the certificate has been verified.

If you want to redirect from `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`, the certificate obtained for `https://domain.com` must be valid for `domain.com` (and then, the certificate obtained for `https://www.domain.com` must be valid for `www.domain.com`).

(You could use two different certificates with Server Name Indication if the two hosts are served on the same IP address, but this is rather convoluted.)

The easiest would be to obtain a certificate that's valid for both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. This can be done using a single certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Name entries. Most CAs should be able to issue such certificates. Some do it without additional fee.

Answer (score 1):

A redirect response is issued through the HTTP protocol. In order to receive such a response/command, the client first needs to establish an HTTP connection. If the client is trying to establish an HTTP_S_ connection, then the SSL negotiation needs to complete first.

In other words, no. The URL `https://domain.com` is invalid for your app. No client should even know about this particular address and hence should not try to access it. You should avoid giving out this URL anywhere so clients won't try to access it. In fact, you do not seem to want to run an HTTPS server for that domain, so you should actually turn it off, so clients won't be able to connect to `domain.com` via HTTPS at all.

Answer (score 1):

---

The best solution I have found is simply to buy a new SSL certificate with subject alternative names so you can have www and non-www in the same certificate and both are valid.  This way you can safely redirect https://www to https:// transparently and without any certificate errors.