# IIS 7 Rewrite Rule with SSL Redirect

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting

I am having and problem using IIS Rewrite rules to handle all scenarios of redirecting an old domain to my newdomain and newly enforcing a SSL connection.

Here are the rules as I have them configured now.

[image: Code]

So what does work is when a user enters in the old domain using http://
Also, If a use enters in the newdomain using http://

What does not work is when a user enters in the olddomain using https://
The user is presented with the error "SSL cert does not match the domain".

Any one have any thoughts on how to combine both these rules to handle all scenarios.

Comment: When the user enters in the olddomain using https://, is he redirect to the new domain? Why did you put a picture instead of copy/paste the XML? :)

Comment: No the user is presented with a warning that the certificate for the newdomain.com does not match the URL olddomain.com entered into the browser address bar.  If the user acknowledges the discrepancy and says continue anyway, the result of the request if a 404 not found on the old domain.    I used a picture as I could not get the "code" format to encapsulate all the XML properly.

Comment: Is the old domain binded to the same web site (the one with the new certificate)? If yes then that makes sense because the certificate issued for domain.com is not valid for oldomain.com

Comment: Upon writing the my previous comment I realized that I did not have a host header bound to the olddomain.com on port 443.  Hence why I was getting the 404 not found.  I added a binding for 443 to olddomain.com and assigned the newdomain certificate to it.  Now I still get the security exception saying the domain on the cert does not match the domain I entered, but upon accepting this I an now properly redirected to the site https://newdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

So things just started clicking in my brain and I believe I have found my own answer.  The answer is I can't do it the way I am doing it.

I found the reason why in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929534/redirect-to-www-before-ssl-requirement)

Since the SSL handshake is done before any requests are made that would be handled by URL Rewrite module, I have to have both certificates active on the site.  Now since this is IIS, and a ssl cert can only be assigned to a single IP, I am going to have to get a second public IP and assign the olddomain bindings to new ip and then the url rewrite rules as I have written should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late addition, but better late than never. To clarify something, IIS will only allow you to assign one SSL certificate per site, not per IP. If you setup your site binding to specify a host name in addition/instead of the IP, you should be able to have multiple site entries each with their own SSL cert, all on the same IP and serving the same content.