# IIS pipeline: what goes first: URL Rewrite or binding?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate, iis-8

What happens first in the pipeline: a URL Rewrite (as defined in the URL Rewrite module of IIS), or a binding mapping?  If some user puts in https://www.mydomain.com it works fine, but for https://mydomain.com browser gives certificate error Do I have to buy a new certificate for mydomain.com, is there any way around of this problem using URL Rewriting Can I use URL Rewriting to redirect to redirect https://mydomain.com to https://www.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had same issue. 
Certifcate Binding (SSL Handshake) first and then URL Rewrite Module.

This post clarified for me: [Redirect to 'www' before ssl requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929534/redirect-to-www-before-ssl-requirement)

Instead of getting another certificate for https://mydomain.com we requested to get Subject Alternative Name in the https://www.mydomain.com certificate.

You can look at how SAN works http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Yes our certificate has SAN with www.domain.com and domain.com. But I can't configure IIS to work properly. What should I do to avoid getting certificate warning?

Comment: Dont recollect doing anything special on IIS. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: So ok. Thanks. We just need to add two binding for two domains with www and without. Thanks a lot!!!