# Firefox won't redirect from HTTP to HTTPS properly?

Tags: firefox, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to redirect the users from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (because SSL cert is valid for the later only), and this works great in Chrome with this code:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443){
    // We are on https version
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) == 'www.example.com'){
        // Wrong domain: Redirect to safety
        header('Location: https://example.com/', true, 301);
        exit();
    }else{
        // We are safe
        die('SSL certificate OK: Your credit card is now safe');
    }

}else{
    // Redirect to safety
    header('Location: https://example.com/', true, 301);
    exit();
}
```

However, **Firefox** refuses to redirect and it keeps showing the usual **INSECURE SITE: Leave this page now or your credit card will be stolen, etc.** warning and that's it. Is there some workaround to force this Firefox to FIRST redirect and THEN check the SSL certificate, as Chrome already does?

Note: I'm not using IIS so I don't need to check the value of the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, it works as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you keep running afoul of the invalid certifcate error is due to how [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) works. Namely, the HTTP connection is tunneled over TLS. This means that the client initiates the TLS connection to the web server (including the process of verifying the server certificate) before getting to the HTTP layer, where your redirect takes place. The result is the browser never sees your redirect because Firefox choked on the certificate before the web server could respond with one.

There are ways of dealing with the `Host` header before completing the TLS handshake, usually involving [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), but that would still require a valid certificate from the server, so doesn't really help you here.

What can help, however, is using a certificate for your domain that would also be valid for the "www" prefix, e.g. `example.com` and `www.example.com`. Most certificate authorities provide this feature for any SSL certificate they issue at no extra charge, as long as you specified both of the domains in the certificate request. (If you need further info on this, let me know.)

To more directly answer your question: **No, you cannot bypass the certificate check due to how the protocol works**, this is intentional behaviour. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34148733/4087397).

Comment: Thank you, please don't forget to vote the question otherwise the site will block me from asking again in the future.